# Dockerized Nginx reverse proxy returning 502 error

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two docker containers running on my server - Nginx on port 80 and another service running on port 7000.

I am trying to get a reverse proxy set-up so hitting the `/service` route redirects to port 7000 on the same machine.

From my client, I can hit the Nginx index.html route just fine (`http://192.168.1.103`), but the reverse proxy route (`http://192.168.1.103/service`) fails with a 502 Bad Gateway error.

I have a single Nginx docker volume mounted to the `/etc/nginx` directory. This contains an `html/` directory and a `nginx.conf` file. The `default.conf` file remains untouched within the container.

This is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
 server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   server_name _;

   location /service {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:7000/;
   }
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try to pass the container name of your service instead of localhost?

Comment: Interesting, I just tried that and the correct tab title loads and the 502 is gone, but I get 404 errors for js and css files like `GET http://192.168.1.103/initialize.js` - which I believe should actually look like `GET http://192.168.1.103/service/initialize.js`. I've tried this with a few different services, and none of them load correctly, so I suspect something is still wrong in my Nginx config. But thanks, this did solve my immediate problem.